# How can I convert or translate C++ define macros so I can use them in C#

Tags: c#

I have the following macros I'm trying to convert.

```
#define FIELD_OFFSET(type, field)    ((LONG)&(((type *)0)->field))
#define IMAGE_FIRST_SECTION(ntheader) ((PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER) ((DWORD)ntheader + \ 
FIELD_OFFSET( IMAGE_NT_HEADERS, OptionalHeader ) + \
((PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)(ntheader))->FileHeader.SizeOfOptionalHeader))
```

I'm pretty green with C++.. could someone give me a hand please?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

[c# doesn't support macros.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/09/why-doesn-t-c-support-define-macros.aspx)

Just create them as functions.  The only *real* advantage to macros in c++ is that you're forcing an inline.  The compiler in C# will be smart enough to make the inline decision for you.

It's really hard to give you an example from the examples you gave me, mostly because they don't 'make sense' in c#, but I'll try to give you an idea:

```
#define AddNumbers(x,y)    x+y
```

can be translated to:

```
public Int32 AddNumbers( Int x, Int y )
{
    return x+y;
}
```

EDIT:

The guys below had a point that I had simplified the conversion TOO much.  My point was more to show the structure, not the actual conversion process.

Comment: These aren't going to work when literally translated as if they were functions.  Moreover, the goal is apparently to get a memory address through pointer arithmetic, which IIRC isn't the C# way to do things.  The OP might do better by understanding the use of the macros and rewriting the code using them.

Comment: Thank you very much! :)  I've been reading quite a bit on these macros but the ones I have are throwing me. I've been trying to find a C# version of PEDump or DumpBin to give me a list of imports? in a DLL.

Comment: Your GetField translation is wrong. The macro is used to return a fixed byte offset.`field` is an argument to the marco, which in the case of the `IMAGE_FIRST_SECTION` macro would seems like it could have its FIELD_OFFSET macro usage replaced with `(long)(sizeof(DWORD) + sizeof(IMAGE_FILE_HEADER))`

Comment: You both have a point - my conversion was simplified too much.  I was more trying to show the STRUCTURE of how one would convert rather than the actual conversion of this macro.  I've simplified/updated my answer.  @JimMacDiarmid I'll need more info on types if you need more specific help!